# elastic search with newer Java takes way more RAM then it should

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I just installed the [latest](https://www.elastic.co/start) stable ELK.
Everything worked well and the ES instance took about 1.3 GB RAM which is ok.  I noticed the following log warning in the CLI that running ES:

```
"warning: usage of JAVA_HOME is deprecated, use ES_JAVA_HOME"
Future versions of Elasticsearch will require Java 11; your Java version from [C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-8u292-b10\jre] does not meet this requirement. Consider switching to a distribution of Elasticsearch with a bundled JDK
```

so I've listened to this advice and added `ES_JAVA_HOME=D:\Software\ELK\elasticsearch-7.14.0\jdk` (used a the newer Java bundled with ELK) and restarted the ES instance.

the warning solved but then I've noticed the ES instance taking 8.5 GB RAM and filled 97% of my RAM usage. expect to the java version I did not change anything. I look for answers in stackoverflow and saw similar question but none of them exactly relate to mine.

the newer Java:

```
JAVA_VERSION="16.0.1"
JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2021-04-20"
```

the older:

```
JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_292"
```

I can say that it seems that ES is working just fine with the older Java so why should I upgrade java and let ES take 100% of my RAM? there's something I can do to use the newer Java without consuming so much RAM?

related - [jvm - ES matrix support](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_jvm)

Comment: I guess old java was 32 bit and new is 64. You can set max memory, but I don't know how to do it in your case. You need to add `-Xmx1500m` to java command line arguments.

Comment: It is also possible that there's a lot of unreclaimed garbage in the heap. Some jvm's are not that eager to collect garbage.

Comment: are you referring to heap or to system memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I could solve it(following [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/advanced-configuration.html#set-jvm-heap-size)) and manually set the maximum heap size. for example, I wanted ES to take no more them 2GB RAM so I've created `$ES_ROOT/config/jvm.options.d/myOptions.options` file with the following content:

```
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
```

it limits es to be around 2-2.5 GB RAM. well, it still does not explains why newer java takes way more memory than an old one.